# Insert an image into Swift Playgrounds for iPad

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

Can you insert an image into Swift Playgrounds for iPad?

I tried adding an image into source code (from + menu, select a photo from album) and just receive an error message with no fix.

If this is not possible, what other methods I have to add image into the project?

Comment: hey @Lim Thye Chean try my solution given below, is this right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to add `import UIKit` at the top of your playground file and then images will work.

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy, just follow the steps

**STEP:1**
In the XCode menu just select View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector:

You’ll see a panel on the right hand side. The Playground Settings section will have your path to the Resource folder. Just click the little arrow, and open up the Resource folder!

**STEP: 2**
Now just add your images in the Resources folder, and code away!

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: These are instructions for XCode on the Mac. This answer is wrong.